# when jquery's css change will be shown in browser?

Tags: jquery, css

My javascript runs like this on firebug:

```
 tr=$(this).parent('tr');
 tr.find('.img-delete').css('display','block');
```

but I can't see the change on the browser. Is there anything I can do to make it shown?

Update:

First I didn't know (or remember) it should show as soon as the change made. I have UI items on a thickbox, I was able to catch events of the items in the window and changed css accordingly. But it didn't show. So my question goes.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more? I am not sure I am quite getting what the problem is. For me both Firefox and Firebug have always shown what I would expect.

Comment: Have you assigned a DOM element to the variable represented by `tr`? If not, try using `$('tr').find('.img-delete')...`

Comment: @DavidThomas tr is an jquery object. Sorry I was hasty to make the question. I will update my code shortly.

Comment: so what is `this` during the statement `tr=$(this).parent('tr')`? Not sure if it will make much difference, but try changing `parent` to `closest`.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy this is in this case textbox `<input type="text">`

Comment: The comments on http://api.jquery.com/parent/ seem quite interesting. One post states that `.parent` only goes up one level, whereas `.parents` goes up multiple levels. I imagine that you have the textarea inside a td / th inside the tr, right? If so, this is probably the answer - if not, you're not using valid HTML. Let me know if this helps and I will post it as an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy You were right. Thanks a lot. And I thought I am good at jquery :-)

Comment: Just added an answer and then realised that David Thomas posted one after my last comment, which has already been accepted... oh well... btw you may well be good at jQuery... I have over 2 years of solid experience of it and I still learn new things every day, but the fact that I learn new things every day doesn't mean I am not good at it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, in this instance, you're responding to an event on an element within a table-cell, may I suggest (as related in the comments to your question):

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.img-delete').show();
```

[JS Fiddle demo/proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xrgkH/).

I've switched from `parent()` to `closest()`, as `parent()` only looks at the immediate *parent*, rather than working its way up the DOM tree of the element's ancestor elements. As the parent of the `input` is not, and cannot, in valid HTML, be, the `tr` element `parent()` will return a null, undefined or false (or falsey) value, rather than an element to work upon.

The reason I suggest `closest()`, as opposed to `parents()` is that `closest()` stops at the first element that matches the selector, and therefore returns a single element, whereas `parents()` continues up the DOM tree of the element's ancestors and returns, potentially, multiple elements in an array.

As you're likely to want to act upon only a single element, `closest()` seems a better match.

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
 $('tr').find('.img-delete').css('display','block');
```

Alternatively,

```
  tr.find('.img-delete').show();
```

This will set the display to block if it is a block element.

What happens when you just enter $('tr').find('.img-delete') into the console in FireBug? Is anything returned by the selector? What are the propertieson it? These are the things that you should be looking at.

Also, what is the tag of the element with the class .img-delete? Is it a 'block' class? I asume it is an img tag, but this might not be the case. If not, look at this page to decide what display style to use:  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.closest` (my preference) or `.parents` instead of `.parent`. The reason for this is that `.parent` only references the immediate parent, whereas the two methods I suggested go up more than one level.

Comment: Sorry buddy. I thought you are one of those guys who don't want to create an answer.

Comment: I prefer to just comment until I have found an answer, and then post a definitive answer to be accepted. Otherwise I risk misunderstanding the question (particularly at this time on a Friday night) and being downvoted.